# How to clear the shipping and country selection only from the session

Tags: session, magento, country

I run Magento with multiple store views.

I would like to know how to clear/destroy the country and the shipping selection when a user changes the store view. I assume this is stored in the session.

I know how to retrieve the session data for the language selection:

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

umask(0);
Mage::app();

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountry_id();

echo $quote;
```

But I don't know how to clear it or unset it before the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my thought and logic it should work for your

As magento provide set and get method for different variable name so in quote also will work for you

just try like below

if the flag is set, making...

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress(null);

OR 

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress->setCountry_id(null);
```

just try or find out in mage core to get your solution.

Comment: @Magento_Beginner, Glad to help you.i would be appreciate,if u vote up so some one can trust our thread n used in future.